# Android - Equilivent of NSOject in Java

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

I have made an iOS project and I have a class of NSObject that gets some data from the web and stores it and then I can call the methods made in that class in other class by importing the NSObject?

I am now making an android version of this app and am wondering how I could go about doing the same thing?

Would I want to make a java class for this? Im not sure what or if there is something that would be similar to this?

Some of the methods in this NSObjects class .m file look like this

```
-(void)populateMenuArray {

self.menuData=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
self.dayMeals=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {
    [self.menuData addObject:[NSMutableDictionary new]];
    [self.dayMeals addObject:[NSMutableArray new]];
}
}
```

And then I have a long method like this to parse some xml from the web and I am trying to replicate this in my android app

```
-(void)parseXML:(NSData *)menuData {
TFHpple *Parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:menuData];
NSString *XpathQueryString = @"//day";

NSArray *Nodes = [Parser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQueryString];

for (TFHppleElement *element in Nodes) {

    NSString *dayString=element.attributes[@"name"];

    MealDay day=[MealData deliDayForString:dayString];

    if (day != MealDayUnknown) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dayDict=(NSMutableDictionary *)self.menuData[day];
        NSMutableArray *dayMeals=self.dayMeals[day];
        NSArray *mealsArray=[element childrenWithTagName:@"meal"];
        for (TFHppleElement *mealElement in mealsArray) {
            NSString *mealName=mealElement.attributes[@"name"];
            [dayMeals addObject:mealName];
            NSMutableDictionary *counterDict=(NSMutableDictionary *)dayDict[mealName];
            if (counterDict == nil) {
                counterDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
                dayDict[mealName]=counterDict;
            }
            NSArray *countersArray=[mealElement childrenWithTagName:@"counter"];
            for (TFHppleElement *counterElement in countersArray) {
                NSString *counterName=counterElement.attributes[@"name"];
                if (counterName != nil) {
                    NSMutableArray *itemsArray=(NSMutableArray *)counterDict[counterName];
                    if (itemsArray == nil) {
                        itemsArray=[NSMutableArray new];
                        counterDict[counterName]=itemsArray;
                    }
                    NSArray *dishArray=[counterElement childrenWithTagName:@"dish"];
                    for (TFHppleElement *dishElement in dishArray) {
                        Items *newItem=[Items new];
                        TFHppleElement *dishNameElement=[dishElement firstChildWithTagName:@"name"];
                        NSString *text=[[dishNameElement firstTextChild].content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
                        newItem.title=text;
                        TFHppleElement *dishUrlElement=[dishElement firstChildWithTagName:@"url"];
                        text=[[dishUrlElement firstTextChild].content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
                        newItem.url=text;
                        [itemsArray addObject:newItem];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Invalid day name %@",dayString);
    }
    }

}
```

So I am trying to replicate the in Android would I use a java class for this? Or is there a better way of going about it?

Thanks for the help in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what part you are struggling with. You do not need an "NSObject equivalent" for what you are doing. Basically you are parsing some XML using XPath. Here is a tutorial to get you started:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Everything else is pretty standard also, you have arrays and strings and that's about it. Let me know exactly what part is puzzling you.